# Вывести данные из БД в Textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

Есть 2 формы: на 1 форме авторизация для пользователя

```
protected async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> db = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        SqlCommand getUsersCredCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Email],[Password] FROM [Users]", sqlConnection);
        SqlDataReader sqlReader = null;
        try
        {
            sqlReader = await getUsersCredCmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
            while (await sqlReader.ReadAsync())
            {
                db.Add(Convert.ToString(sqlReader["Email"]), Convert.ToString(sqlReader["Password"]));

            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Label2.Text = "Вы ввели неправильный логин или пароль!";
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (sqlReader != null)
                sqlReader.Close();


        }
        if (TextBox2.Text == db[TextBox1.Text])
        {
            HttpCookie login = new HttpCookie("login", TextBox1.Text);
            HttpCookie sign = new HttpCookie("sign", SignGenerator.GetSign(TextBox1.Text + "bytepp"));
            Response.Cookies.Add(login);
            Response.Cookies.Add(sign);
            Response.Redirect("userpage.aspx", false);
        }
    }
```

На 2 форме мне нужно отобразить данные о вошедшем клиенте ФИО и телефон.

```
public partial class userpage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Northwind"].ConnectionString);

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        HttpCookie login = Request.Cookies["login"];
        HttpCookie sign = Request.Cookies["sign"];


        String insertCmd = "select FIO FROM Clients WHERE Email='"+ login +"'";
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=USER-ПК\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB_fitnes;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(insertCmd.ToString(), myConnection);
        myConnection.Open();
        SqlDataReader rd;
        rd = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while (rd.Read())
        {
            TextBox1.Text = rd[0].ToString();
        }

        if (login != null && sign != null)
        {
            if (sign.Value == SignGenerator.GetSign(login.Value + "bytepp"))
            {
                Label1.Text = login.Value;
                return;
            }

        }
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");

    }
```

Что не так? Вывожу для начала только ФИО. Не отображает.
Вот БД и запуск программы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А отладкой смотрели, есть ли данные в 'rd'?

Comment: Да есть. Если убрать +login+ выводит последнее ФИО в таблице

Comment: У меня все получилось добавила +login.Value+

Comment: Не могли бы вы подсказать как вы обошли ситуацию когда на странице входа в TextBox ничего нет. У меня выходит ошибка (System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: "Данный ключ отсутствует в словаре.")